# Howto make JavaFX Dialog NOT closing itself after pressing OK Button

Tags: java, javafx, dialog

currently I am using `Dialog<User> loginDialog = new Dialog<>();` to create a login dialog in which the user needs to input his username and password and then click the OK button to login.

### My Issue

Unfortunately the dialog pane closes itself each time the ok button was pressed no matter whether the login was successful or not. I would like the dialog pane only to close itself when either the cancel button was pressed or the login was successful.

### SOLUTION

as NwDX has pointed out. One need to make use of the addEventFilter method. My implementation of it looks like this:

```
btnLogin.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> {
            if (!comboAdministrator.getValue().getPassword().equals(pfLogin.getText())) {
                lblErrorNotification.setText("Password is incorrect. Try again!");
                pfLogin.requestFocus();
                event.consume();
            }
        });
```

**Explanation**: the eventfilter catches any unmatching passwords and send an error message to a label node for notification purposes. The event.consume() is neccessary, otherwise the dialog will revert to its original behaviour by closing itself once again.

### SOLUTION with complete code

```
private Optional<User> showLoginDialog() {

        Dialog<User> dialog = new Dialog<>();
        dialog.setTitle("Administrator Login");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Enter administrator password");
        dialog.initOwner(btnShowManagerView.getScene().getWindow());
        dialog.getDialogPane().getStylesheets().add("util/resources/myCSS.css");

        dialog.setGraphic(new ImageView(ResourceClass.class.getResource("locker.png").toString()));

        ButtonType loginButtonType = new ButtonType("Login", ButtonData.YES);
        ButtonType cancelButtonType = ButtonType.CANCEL;

        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(loginButtonType, cancelButtonType);

        Label lblErrorNotification = new Label();
        lblErrorNotification.setTextFill(Color.RED);

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setHgap(10);
        gridPane.setVgap(10);
        gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(20, 150, 20, 20));

        ComboBox<User> comboAdministrator = new ComboBox();
        comboAdministrator.setItems(main.getAdministrators());
        comboAdministrator.setValue(main.getAdministrators().get(0));
        comboAdministrator.setConverter(new StringConverter<User>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(User object) {
                return object.getLoginName();
            }

            @Override
            public User fromString(String string) {
                return null;
            }
        });
        main.enableComboBoxBaseShowIfFocused(comboAdministrator);

        PasswordField pfLogin = new PasswordField();

        gridPane.add(new Label("AdminUser"), 0, 0);
        gridPane.add(comboAdministrator, 1, 0);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Password"), 0, 1);
        gridPane.add(pfLogin, 1, 1);
        gridPane.add(lblErrorNotification, 1, 2);

        Button btnLogin = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(loginButtonType);

        btnLogin.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> {
            if (!comboAdministrator.getValue().getPassword().equals(pfLogin.getText())) {
                lblErrorNotification.setText("Password is incorrect. Try again!");
                pfLogin.requestFocus();
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        btnLogin.disableProperty()
                .bind(pfLogin.textProperty().isEmpty());

        dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(gridPane);

        Platform.runLater(()
                -> comboAdministrator.requestFocus());

        dialog.setResultConverter((ButtonType buttonType) -> {
            if (buttonType == loginButtonType) {
                return comboAdministrator.getValue();
            }

            return null;
        });

        return dialog.showAndWait();
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Dialog API Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html):

> Dialog Validation / Intercepting Button Actions
>
> In some circumstances it is desirable to prevent a dialog from closing
>   until some aspect of the dialog becomes internally consistent (e.g. a
>   form inside the dialog has all fields in a valid state). To do this,
>   users of the dialogs API should become familiar with the
>   DialogPane.lookupButton(ButtonType) method. By passing in a ButtonType
>   (that has already been set in the button types list), users will be
>   returned a Node that is typically of type Button (but this depends on
>   if the DialogPane.createButton(ButtonType) method has been
>   overridden). With this button, users may add an event filter that is
>   called before the button does its usual event handling, and as such
>   users may prevent the event handling by consuming the event. Here's a
>   simplified example:

```
 final Button btOk = (Button) dlg.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK);
 btOk.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> {
     if (!validateAndStore()) {
         event.consume();
     }
 });
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks a lot for your efforts. I have learned from you that next time I should peruse through the Java API Doc myself before I post a question to the community.

Comment: @Chiggiddi This is a matter of taste :-) So this post is helpful to other ones searching for the same thing. Please mark it as the answer (green hook), thank you.

Comment: yep :) you are totally right. Just hooked you up with green and looking forward to have this post help others in need!